Does food go bad on the ISS? How often is food thrown away?
How often does food spoil on the ISS, and how much food is thrown away on the ISS?
I imagine there would be a different answer between the preserved long duration food and the fresh produce available right after a new craft arrives.
Bonus question: how are things some would throw away but not others handled? For example if one astronaut peels the apple and throws the skin, but another would have eaten it with the skin.

there's also that tomato that "got lost" for a while

Partial answer covering "How often does food spoil on the ISS" and the US side only

...instances of spoiled food packages on the
International Space Station have been recorded once a year on average but have not resulted in
foodborne illness. The crew is trained to identify bloated or spoiled packages and discard them.

(emphasis mine)
I couldn't find an answer to the "how much food is thrown away" part but this quote was relevant

...crew are trained to discard food that
they have not consumed within two hours of rehydrating (if freeze-dried) or opening (if retort or
irradiated), as these conditions may allow microorganisms to grow. This time limit decreases with
increasing temperatures.

Source: Evidence Report:
Risk of Performance Decrement and Crew Illness Due to
Inadequate Food and Nutrition
Section F in the report, International Space Station Food System – Current State might be of interest to you.
